# Can't make custom desktop launcher launchable

Tags: gnome

I am on Ubuntu 20.04. My GNOME Shell is at version 3.36.4. I am using GNOME Tweaks to show files on the desktop.

An example of what works: In Terminal, I type `cp /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.org ~/Desktop`. On the desktop (NOT from Nautilus), I right-click the icon of a gear on a paper sheet with the caption `org.gnome.Terminal.…` and there is `Allow Launching`. I click that menu entry and the icon is changed to Terminal's icon and the caption now says `Terminal`.

What doesn't work: I create a file under `~/Desktop` with the name `Reboot-into-Text-Mode.desktop`. I edit the file so that it reads

```
[Desktop]
Name=Reboot into Text Mode
Exec=pkexec /opt/scripts/kexec-text
```

From Terminal, I run chmod +x ~/Desktop/Reboot-into-Text-Mode.desktop`. When I right click the corresponding icon on the desktop (NOT from Nautilus), I am given a context menu that does NOT contain` Allow Launching`. I want to be able to run this command by clicking a desktop shortcut and not just from the terminal.

How can I make my `.desktop` file launchable? Why can't I make it launchable when I was able to make Terminal's `.desktop` file launchable?